# Git rebase to remote branch with history preserved

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-workflow

We have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979599/git-reverts-commit-unexpectedly-after-merge) that could be raised by `merge` workflow so we are considering using `rebase` workflow instead.

One concern is that `rebase` on remote repository results in rewrite of history. But I think this can be fixed by

1. Mark a `tag` (can be names `branch_rebaseXXXXXXXX` where `XXXXXXXX` is a timestamp) on the branch you are going to rebase
2. Push the `tag`
3. Apply `rebase`
4. Push

Git may prevents you from doing `rebase` on remote, even you followed the above to preserve the history. Instead of `git push --force` hack,  we can do

1. Create a new branch `branch_new` on top of `branch`
2. Mark a tag as above
3. Rebase the new branch
4. Push the new branch and the tag
5. Delete the old local and remote `branch`
6. Rename the `branch_new` to `branch`
7. Push the change of branch names

When applying this approach and uses only `rebase` not `merge` strictly from beginning, although the resulting commit history would not be linear, but since there will be no merges, it will effectively form a tree-like graph where each leaf node is either a tip of an active branch, or marked by a tag. Personally, I would call those tags "tombstones".

As the above approach was not used in practice yet, what would be the pros and cons of this approach? Especially, what would happen if someone checked out a branch, working on it, and then another guy marked a tombstone on that branch?

Comment: It sounds like all you've done is confused the `--force` check. The net effect is what's important and it's identical to a rebase-force-push so has the same effect on anyone pulling the repository.

Comment: Yes, it could be the same as `--force` but the point here is, by tagging the rebasing branch, it avoids part of the history being destroyed in the public repository. This is important since the rebased commits would be different from the original ones if there are any conflicts to resolve. IMHO  that `rebase` allows the original commits being "removed" is a design mistake.

Comment: Also, it is still worth to use the workaround. `git push --force` can be terrible if you have just forgotten to use `git tag` first. So by following the steps above, although it is harder, effectively reduces the risk to do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a situation where someone dropped the entire history with a bad `push --force` so I'm not keen on your workaround.

Okay, for [whatever reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979599/git-reverts-commit-unexpectedly-after-merge) you want your official history to be linear.  But you still want full visibility for some working branches.

You want a `pu` branch.

A "Pending updates" branch gets re-rebased continually, you put into the configuration of the remote that this branch will always be force-pushed. On the server you have the option to add a script to create a reference (maybe a tag maybe neither a tag nor a branch) if it isn't a fast-forward push. Each user (or group) needs their own `pu` branch.

The master branch gets updated ONLY with fast-forwards and only with plain commits, no merges.

*Someone* (to be decided) takes the commits, when requested, and adds them (cherry-pick'd ?) onto the master branch. This person does NOT do merges, the merge (physically it'll be fixing the rebase) happens on the `pu` branches not here.

That *someone* can do something else too ... **testing**. They add the patches to their own "testing" branch if the tests succeed the master is fast-forwarded. If the tests fail the test branch is bisected and the bad patch (or patches) are returned to sender before retesting.

About the automatically created references, git does deal well with huge numbers of references, but these do seem (to me) to have a short expiry time. It may well be enough to just turn on the reflog on the server. OTOH if you do want to keep them forever a `merge -s ours` onto a `work-history` branch would make for an impressive `log --graph` with no other references needed.

You might feel that you want to get away with just the server script and letting the users rebase master. My problem with that is that you need a fixed point, some way to say "that's now in the official history, you must not change it". Without it your developers may end up changing commits that have left your control (gone to production or customers). The push to master is that mark.

Comment: I can't see any real objection in your post yet. Yes you described a scenario here, but it does not seem to be harmful in **ANY** way. The only thing seems to be negative is *huge number of references... have a short expiry time* but this is a minor issue. Anyway, simply turning on `reflog` does not help because it is not visible to the clients. I need the references to be visible and so people can see it and understand what happened.

Comment: Another thing is that *you need a fixed point...* and I agree. The "tombstones" in my proposal plays the role of fixed point of history. People shall not attempt to move them, rename them or remove them, since they are part of the history.

Comment: Um, no, your tombstone refs are pointers to what *has already changed* there will be commits that are between a tombstone ref and the merge-base with the master that leave the building. You would have to freeze the master (eg use a pending update) if you want to be sure that every commit that leaves the building is on the master's direct history and so can be easily bisected. If you use your tombstones you will have to keep all the tombstones that may contain published commits.

Comment: You won't have a linear history (eg: git describe as V1.2+23commits) you will have to use the hash to identify the commit and bisect may have to go backwards. There is also no limit to how far back you might have to go. Oh, and with the *pu* method most people won't have to understand the *work-history* they'll only need the linear *master* history as that's all that could have *left the building*.